# accessing another js file with out html

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a javascript file that stores an object. It is called file_system.js. In main.js, I need to access this object, change it, and save the file. How I would link the file_system.js to main.js all in js and no html? Changing it would also be in js. Saving the file, I don't care what language it is in as long as it gets the job done. I know a bit of php but I haven't ever used it in a project. I just took some codecademy courses on it. The overall project is an html document.

file_system.js

```
files = {
    "obj1": "hi",
    "obj2": "bye"
};
```

main.js

```
files["obj1"] = "hello";
alert(files["obj1"]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's a strange way to go about things.. But, you'll need to look into ajax! You can use it to read and write to the server via a php interface.

Comment: Or Web Workers as well, especially since it's an object

Comment: do you know how to link one js script to another without html?